# Create animations programmatically in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game I have a big catalog of gear: Armors, weapons and shields. The combinations between these can be really immense.

[image]

Besides that, the player has the option of switching in-game to a different set of armor-weapon combination. In the end to solve this, I have used the following object structure.

[image]

Whenever I switch the weapons, I activate/deactivate the necessary GameObjects. The animations are set in this way:

[image]

Now, the problem is creating the animation. I first considered pre-rendering programatically all the combinations, but my catalog is so huge, that it would create 100s, if not 1000s of animations. So I opted for a different solution. Create in playtime the animation, once I knew what gear would the player select. For that, I created a script to take care of that. The problem is that I have been using APIs from `UnityEditor`, and now I have realized the build will not work. Specifically because of 2 different classes: `EditorCurveBinding` and `ObjectReferenceKeyframe`.

This is a couple snippets of how I was using this classes when creating the animations:

```cs
static EditorCurveBinding GetEditorCurveBinding(string path = "")
{
    EditorCurveBinding spriteBinding = new EditorCurveBinding();
    spriteBinding.type = typeof(SpriteRenderer);
    spriteBinding.path = path;
    spriteBinding.propertyName = "m_Sprite";

    return spriteBinding;
}
```

```cs
static ObjectReferenceKeyframe GetKeyframe(float time, Sprite sprite)
{
    ObjectReferenceKeyframe keyframe = new ObjectReferenceKeyframe();
    keyframe.time = time / FRAMERATE;
    keyframe.value = sprite;
    return keyframe;
}
```

Now, the problem with the Curve, I think I managed to solve, replacing it with this code, replacing `EditorCurveBinding` with `AnimationCurve`:

```
AnimationClip clip = ...
AnimationCurve curve = new AnimationCurve();
clip.SetCurve(path, typeof(SpriteRenderer), "m_Sprite", curve);
```

But I have no idea how to set the sprites for each animation. I thought that using `curve.AddKey`could be helpful, but I have seen no way to add a sprite there.

How could I rewrite that code to avoid using `UnityEditor`?

[Full code](https://pastebin.com/TYJzPwip)

Comment: If the animation is always the same for a class of equipment (eg swords) why not create a parent object that contains the animations and then add the specific sword  as a child? That would decouple the animation from the gear and you would only need to create a limited set of animations.

Comment: You mean to create separate animations for each gear, and spread the animations on different game objects? Have I understood correctly?

Comment: Not for each individual gear, but only for each class of gear. e.g. one animation for all swords, one for all spears, one for all shields etc. Then you can have a gameobject without any graphics handling the motions and append the actual graphics/stats/logic of the gear as a child.

Comment: The problem is the animator. A State machine can only control one animation at the time. It would not be able to control a separate animation for each class of gear.

Comment: Why not having one animator per gear then and triggering it in your player script using parameters? Otherwise you'll have to deal with multiple concurrent animations anyway, e.g. slashing & walking at the same time.

Comment: Because then I would have to make sure that the animators are perfectly synchronized. I already tried this approach and it is super hard. State machines run independently from each other. Not even sure if it is possible.

Comment: I've worked on a project like this. It started with Unity FSM animations and quickly made 180 turn to [Spine](http://en.esotericsoftware.com/spine-in-depth). With Spine, you can animate your character with all of the equipment, and at run-time replace specific textures. If you'd consider Spine, I could give you access to a demo project.

Comment: Do you think that would work with the kind of pixel-art sprites that I have? There is almost nothing "riggable" in my sprites. Most do not have more than 80 pixels in any dimension.

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent oh definitely, Spine allows you to make point bones which act like Unity's Transform component, position, rotation, scale.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I would completely avoid built-in Animator and Animations, since this tool is for the very narrow purpose of animating a single object in a predefined way (eg: for a cutscene).

## Offtopic - performance

> Besides that, the player has the option of switching in-game to a different set of armor-weapon combination. In the end to solve this, I have used the following object structure.

As you probably know this is very inefficient memory-wise and will decrease performance (disabled objects still have marginal CPU overhead). And will incread load time and instantiation time of new objects.

## Can I use Animator or Animation?

Because Animator has no API to access it's internals and animation type and overall you cannot do pretty mutch nothing with it except from telling it to [Play or Stop](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/61f92bd79ae862c4465d35270f9d1d57befd1761/Modules/Animation/ScriptBindings/Animator.bindings.cs#L283).
Since I understand that your animation is "Sprite based" and not "Transform based" any sane idea is just inefficient!

Best solution that I vow against is as follows:

- Create "trigger points" that you would "animate"
- Based on trigger point - change sprite

```
    public class AnimationController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public int AnimationIndex;
        public Sprite[] AnimationSprites;
        public SpriteRenderer SpriteRenderer;
        
        private void Update()
        {
            SpriteRenderer.sprite = AnimationSprites[AnimationIndex];
        }
    }
```

[image]

## Better solution?

Since we already need to have custom structure that manages our sprites we might want to optimize the whole thing, since we are not using almost any of the features of Animator we could write custom controller that would replace Animator in this case. This should improve performance significantly since Animator is very heavy!

```
    // MonoBehaviour is optional here
    public class SpriteRendererAnimationHandler
    {
        // More fields that would control the animation timing
        
        public Sprite[] AnimationSprites;
        public SpriteRenderer SpriteRenderer;
        
        public void OnAnimationUpdate(int index)
        {
            var resolvedIndex = ResolveIndex(index);
            SpriteRenderer.sprite = AnimationSprites[resolvedIndex];
        }

        private int ResolveIndex(int index)
        {
            // Resolve animation index to sprite array index
        }
    }

    // One controller per character - or global per game that synchronize all animations to locked FPS 12.
    public class AnimationController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private List<SpriteRendererAnimationHandler> Handlers = new List<SpriteRendererAnimationHandler>();

        public void FixedUpdate()
        {
            foreach (var handler in Handlers)
            {
                // Calculate animation index
                int calculatedAnimationIndex = ...;
                handler.OnAnimationUpdate(calculatedAnimationIndex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Building my own Animation system seems really overkill! Are there no other existing ones that can be used?

Comment: The first solution is the best one you can use with the existing Animation system, which is a custom class that stores your images, and "animate" the index. Otherwise, as you mentioned you would need thousands of animations that you can generate via Editor scripts.

Comment: But doesnt that mean that I have to set up an animation event on EVERY SINGLE keyframe?

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question correctly. You don't have to set up an animation event on every single keyframe. You need to make animation events every so often when sprite needs to change. As you currently have with sprites, but with indexes instead. Eg: If in your attack animation shield has always the same sprite, but different from idle animation then you need to set index (sprite) at the beginning of the animation.

Comment: "You don't have to set up an animation event on every single keyframe. You need to make animation events every so often when sprite needs to change" <-- A keyframe is exactly that... the moment a sprite has to change....

Answer (score 0):

Add a public field named animation index to Tomasz last example, then create the animations in animator as youd normal do for animation pieces, then animate that animation index field. simple if(currentAnimationyion != lastAnimationIndex) to check if need to send to handlers and ya rocking