# Index for sprites does not seem to update

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to follow the example in this question [Create animations programmatically in Unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66186689/create-animations-programmatically-in-unity/66245984) to programmatically update my hero (GameObject) sprite based on an array and an index (because I'd rather not create thousands of animations for different equipment), then do the same for the children via use of the index. The structure is as follows:

[image]

For that, I have the following:

Script to update the children, SpritePosition.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SpritePosition : MonoBehaviour {
  [SerializeField] private string objectName;
  [SerializeField] private int objectIndex;
  [SerializeField] private int objectR;
  [SerializeField] private int objectG;
  [SerializeField] private int objectB;
  private Rigidbody2D body;
  private SpriteRenderer objectRenderer;
  private GameObject hero;
  private Rigidbody2D heroRigidBody;
  private SpriteRenderer heroRenderer;
  // private Sprite currentHeroSprite;
  private AnimationController animationControllerScript;
  private int currentHeroSpriteIndex;
  private HeroResources heroResourcesScript;
  private HeroMovement heroMovementScript;
  private Sprite[] spriteGroup;

  private void Start() {
    body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    objectRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

    hero = GameObject.Find("Hero");
    heroRigidBody = hero.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    heroRenderer = hero.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    animationControllerScript = hero.GetComponent<AnimationController>();
    currentHeroSpriteIndex = animationControllerScript.currentHeroSpriteIndex;

    heroResourcesScript = hero.GetComponent<HeroResources>();
    spriteGroup = heroResourcesScript.spriteGroup[objectName][objectIndex];
  }

  private void Update() {
    heroMovementScript = hero.GetComponent<HeroMovement>();

    SetSprite();
    SetPosition();
  }
  
  private void SetSprite() {
    objectRenderer.sprite = spriteGroup[currentHeroSpriteIndex];

    objectRenderer.color = new Color(objectR, objectG, objectB, 1);
    transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
  }

  // for this to work, the game object must have a
  // RigidBody2D component with Freeze Position active
  // for X and Y axis
  private void SetPosition() {
    Vector2 currentHeroPosition = heroRigidBody.position;
    transform.position = currentHeroPosition;
  }
}
```

Here I'm using these:

```
animationControllerScript = hero.GetComponent<AnimationController>();
currentHeroSpriteIndex = animationControllerScript.currentHeroSpriteIndex;
```

to get the variable `currentHeroSpriteIndex` to get the index updated. This update occurs in AnimationController.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimationController : MonoBehaviour {
  public int currentHeroSpriteIndex = 0;
  private bool grounded;
  private bool falling;
  private bool jumping;
  private bool running;
  private bool horizontalCollision;

  private HeroResources heroResourcesScript;
  private HeroMovement heroMovementScript;
  private GameObject hero;
  private SpriteRenderer heroRenderer;
  private Sprite[] heroSprites;

  private int[] runningSprites = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 };
  private int animationIndex = 0;

  // Start is called before the first frame update
  void Start() {
    hero = GameObject.Find("Hero");
    heroMovementScript = hero.GetComponent<HeroMovement>();
    heroRenderer = hero.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    heroResourcesScript = hero.GetComponent<HeroResources>();
    heroSprites = heroResourcesScript.heroSprites;
  }

  void setHeroSprite(int index) {
    heroRenderer.sprite = heroSprites[index];
  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update() {
    grounded = heroMovementScript.isGrounded;
    falling = heroMovementScript.isFalling;
    jumping = heroMovementScript.isJumping;
    running = heroMovementScript.isRunning;
    horizontalCollision = heroMovementScript.horizontalCollision;

    if (running) {
      currentHeroSpriteIndex = runningSprites[animationIndex % 14];
      setHeroSprite(currentHeroSpriteIndex);
      animationIndex++;
    } else {
      currentHeroSpriteIndex = 0;
      setHeroSprite(currentHeroSpriteIndex);
      animationIndex = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

For now, I only have a specific array for actions, `runningSprites`, which gives me the sprites I use for running animation:

```
private int[] runningSprites = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 };
```

So, in HeroMovement.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class HeroMovement : MonoBehaviour {
  [SerializeField] private float speed;
  [SerializeField] private float jumpHeight;
  private Rigidbody2D body;
  private Animator anim;
  public bool isGrounded;
  public bool isFalling;
  public bool isJumping;
  public bool isFacingLeft;
  public bool isRunning;

  public bool horizontalCollision;

  public int collisionCounter = 0;

  // called when script is loaded
  private void Awake() {
    body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
  }

  // called on every frame of the game
  private void Update() {
    float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float verticalSpeed = body.velocity.y;

    // x axis movement
    if (!horizontalCollision) {
      body.velocity = new Vector2(horizontalInput * speed, body.velocity.y);

      // flip player when moving left
      if (horizontalInput > 0.01f && isGrounded) {
        transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
        isFacingLeft = false;
      }
      // flip player when moving right
      else if (horizontalInput < -0.01f && isGrounded) {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
        isFacingLeft = true;
      }
    }

    // jumping
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded) {
      Jump();
    }

    isRunning = horizontalInput != 0 && !isJumping && !isFalling;

    // set animator parameters
    // anim.SetBool("isRunning", horizontalInput != 0 && !isJumping && !isFalling);
    // anim.SetBool("isGrounded", isGrounded);
    // anim.SetBool("isFalling", isFalling);
    // anim.SetBool("isJumping", isJumping);
    // anim.SetBool("horizontalCollision", horizontalCollision);

    if (!isGrounded && verticalSpeed < -1) {
      Fall();
    }
  }

  private void Fall() {
    isFalling = true;
  }

  private void Jump() {
    body.velocity = new Vector2(body.velocity.x, jumpHeight);
    isJumping = true;
    isGrounded = false;
  }

  private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
    Collider2D collider = collision.collider;
    Collider2D otherCollider = collision.otherCollider;

    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground") {
      if (otherCollider.tag == "Hero") {
        if (!isHorizontalCollision(otherCollider, collider)) {
          isGrounded = true;
          isFalling = false;
          isJumping = false;
          horizontalCollision = false;
        } else {          
          horizontalCollision = true;

          if (isBottomCollision(otherCollider, collider)) {
            horizontalCollision = false;
          }
        }
      }      
    }

    collisionCounter++;
  }

  private bool isBottomCollision(Collider2D collider1, Collider2D collider2) {
    int c1BottomEdge = (int) collider1.bounds.max.y;
    int c2TopEdge = (int) collider2.bounds.min.y;

    return c1BottomEdge == c2TopEdge;
  }

  private bool isHorizontalCollision(Collider2D collider1, Collider2D collider2) {
    int c1RightEdge = (int) collider1.bounds.max.x;
    int c1LeftEdge = (int) collider1.bounds.min.x;

    int c2RightEdge = (int) collider2.bounds.max.x;
    int c2LeftEdge = (int) collider2.bounds.min.x;

    return (c1RightEdge == c2LeftEdge) || (c1LeftEdge == c2RightEdge);
  }

  private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision) {
    collisionCounter--;

    if (collisionCounter == 0) {
      isGrounded = false;
    }
  }

  // private bool isGrounded() {
  //   RaycastHit2D raycastHit = Physics2D.BoxCast(boxCollider.bounds.center, boxCollider.bounds.size, 0, Vector2.down, 0.1f, groundLayer);
  //   return raycastHit.collider != null;
  // }
}
```

I set booleans to verify if the player is running using the following:

```
isRunning = horizontalInput != 0 && !isJumping && !isFalling;
```

then, in the animation script, I get the hero movement and determine if it's running like so:

```
heroMovementScript = hero.GetComponent<HeroMovement>();
.
.
.
running = heroMovementScript.isRunning;
```

then if `running` is `true`, the animation block should run, and (for now since it's the only coded action) stop (revert sprite to 0) if not running:

```
if (running) {
      currentHeroSpriteIndex = runningSprites[animationIndex % 14];
      setHeroSprite(currentHeroSpriteIndex);
      animationIndex++;
    } else {
      currentHeroSpriteIndex = 0;
      setHeroSprite(currentHeroSpriteIndex);
      animationIndex = 0;
    }
```

The problem is, I'm assuming the `currentHeroSpriteIndex` gets assigned the value of the current index in the `runningSprites` array, but when I check the value in SpritePosition.cs via `Debug.Log`, I always get a `0`. Could it have to do with the variable expecting a value in the script properties?

[image]

Also, in case you wish to see it, the script to load all sprites is here, in HeroResources.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HeroResources : MonoBehaviour {
  const int PANTS_LIMIT = 1;
  const int BOOTS_LIMIT = 1;
  const int SHIRT_LIMIT = 1;
  const int TUNIC_LIMIT = 2;
  const int BELT_LIMIT = 1;

  public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, Sprite[]>> spriteGroup = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, Sprite[]>>();
  public Sprite[] heroSprites;

  public Dictionary<int, Sprite[]> getAllSprites(string name, int limit) {
    Dictionary<int, Sprite[]> spriteList = new Dictionary<int, Sprite[]>();

    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
      spriteList.Add(i, Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Spritesheets/" + name + "/" + (i + 1)));
    }

    return spriteList;
  }

  void Awake() {
    spriteGroup.Add("pants", getAllSprites("pants", PANTS_LIMIT));
    spriteGroup.Add("boots", getAllSprites("boots", BOOTS_LIMIT));
    spriteGroup.Add("shirt", getAllSprites("shirt", SHIRT_LIMIT));
    spriteGroup.Add("tunic", getAllSprites("tunic", TUNIC_LIMIT));
    spriteGroup.Add("belt", getAllSprites("belt", BELT_LIMIT));
  }

  void Start() {
    heroSprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Spritesheets/hero-body");
  }
}
```

Please let me know if you have an idea of what is wrong/missing. HeroMovement.cs, HeroResources.cs and AnimationController.cs are attached to the hero game object, while SpritePosition.cs is attached to each of the child game objects.

**UPDATE**

After some more testing and fixes, here is the updated code:

AnimationController.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimationController : MonoBehaviour {
  private float waitTime = 0.06f;
  private float timer = 0.0f;

  private bool grounded;
  private bool falling;
  private bool jumping;
  private bool running;
  private bool horizontalCollision;

  private HeroMovement heroMovementScript;
  private GameObject hero;

  private int[] runningSprites = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 };
  private int animationIndex = 0;

  public int currentHeroSpriteIndex = 0;

  // Start is called before the first frame update
  void Start() {
    hero = GameObject.Find("Hero");
    heroMovementScript = hero.GetComponent<HeroMovement>();
  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update() {
    timer += Time.deltaTime;

    if (timer > waitTime) {
      grounded = heroMovementScript.isGrounded;
      falling = heroMovementScript.isFalling;
      jumping = heroMovementScript.isJumping;
      running = heroMovementScript.isRunning;
      horizontalCollision = heroMovementScript.horizontalCollision;

      if (running) {
        currentHeroSpriteIndex = runningSprites[animationIndex % 14];
        animationIndex++;
      } else {
        currentHeroSpriteIndex = 0;
        animationIndex = 0;
      }

      timer = timer - waitTime;
    }
  }
}
```

HeroMovement.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class HeroMovement : MonoBehaviour {
  [SerializeField] private float speed;
  [SerializeField] private float jumpHeight;
  private Rigidbody2D body;
  private Animator anim;
  private AnimationController animationControllerScript;
  private int currentHeroSpriteIndex;
  private SpriteRenderer heroRenderer;
  private HeroResources heroResourcesScript;
  private Sprite[] heroSprites;
  public bool isGrounded;
  public bool isFalling;
  public bool isJumping;
  public bool isFacingLeft;
  public bool isRunning;

  public bool horizontalCollision;

  public int collisionCounter = 0;

  // called when script is loaded
  private void Awake() {
    body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    animationControllerScript = GetComponent<AnimationController>();
    heroRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    heroResourcesScript = GetComponent<HeroResources>();

    currentHeroSpriteIndex = animationControllerScript.currentHeroSpriteIndex;
    heroSprites = heroResourcesScript.heroSprites;
  }

  private void SetSprite() {
    if (heroSprites.Length != heroResourcesScript.heroSprites.Length) {
      heroSprites = heroResourcesScript.heroSprites;
    }

    if (currentHeroSpriteIndex != animationControllerScript.currentHeroSpriteIndex) {
      currentHeroSpriteIndex = animationControllerScript.currentHeroSpriteIndex;
      heroRenderer.sprite = heroSprites[currentHeroSpriteIndex];
      Debug.Log(heroSprites[currentHeroSpriteIndex].name);
    }
  }

  // called on every frame of the game
  private void Update() {
    SetSprite();

    float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float verticalSpeed = body.velocity.y;

    // x axis movement
    if (!horizontalCollision) {
      body.velocity = new Vector2(horizontalInput * speed, body.velocity.y);

      // flip player when moving left
      if (horizontalInput > 0.01f && isGrounded) {
        transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
        isFacingLeft = false;
      }
      // flip player when moving right
      else if (horizontalInput < -0.01f && isGrounded) {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
        isFacingLeft = true;
      }
    }

    // jumping
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded) {
      Jump();
    }

    isRunning = horizontalInput != 0 && !isJumping && !isFalling;

    // set animator parameters
    // anim.SetBool("isRunning", horizontalInput != 0 && !isJumping && !isFalling);
    // anim.SetBool("isGrounded", isGrounded);
    // anim.SetBool("isFalling", isFalling);
    // anim.SetBool("isJumping", isJumping);
    // anim.SetBool("horizontalCollision", horizontalCollision);

    if (!isGrounded && verticalSpeed < -1) {
      Fall();
    }
  }

  private void Fall() {
    isFalling = true;
  }

  private void Jump() {
    body.velocity = new Vector2(body.velocity.x, jumpHeight);
    isJumping = true;
    isGrounded = false;
  }

  private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
    Collider2D collider = collision.collider;
    Collider2D otherCollider = collision.otherCollider;

    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground") {
      if (otherCollider.tag == "Hero") {
        if (!isHorizontalCollision(otherCollider, collider)) {
          isGrounded = true;
          isFalling = false;
          isJumping = false;
          horizontalCollision = false;
        } else {          
          horizontalCollision = true;

          if (isBottomCollision(otherCollider, collider)) {
            horizontalCollision = false;
          }
        }
      }      
    }

    collisionCounter++;
  }

  private bool isBottomCollision(Collider2D collider1, Collider2D collider2) {
    int c1BottomEdge = (int) collider1.bounds.max.y;
    int c2TopEdge = (int) collider2.bounds.min.y;

    return c1BottomEdge == c2TopEdge;
  }

  private bool isHorizontalCollision(Collider2D collider1, Collider2D collider2) {
    int c1RightEdge = (int) collider1.bounds.max.x;
    int c1LeftEdge = (int) collider1.bounds.min.x;

    int c2RightEdge = (int) collider2.bounds.max.x;
    int c2LeftEdge = (int) collider2.bounds.min.x;

    return (c1RightEdge == c2LeftEdge) || (c1LeftEdge == c2RightEdge);
  }

  private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision) {
    collisionCounter--;

    if (collisionCounter == 0) {
      isGrounded = false;
    }
  }

  // private bool isGrounded() {
  //   RaycastHit2D raycastHit = Physics2D.BoxCast(boxCollider.bounds.center, boxCollider.bounds.size, 0, Vector2.down, 0.1f, groundLayer);
  //   return raycastHit.collider != null;
  // }
}
```

HeroResources.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HeroResources : MonoBehaviour {
  const int PANTS_LIMIT = 1;
  const int BOOTS_LIMIT = 1;
  const int SHIRT_LIMIT = 1;
  const int TUNIC_LIMIT = 2;
  const int BELT_LIMIT = 1;

  public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, Sprite[]>> spriteGroup = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, Sprite[]>>();
  public Sprite[] heroSprites = new Sprite[180];

  public Dictionary<int, Sprite[]> getAllSprites(string name, int limit) {
    Dictionary<int, Sprite[]> spriteList = new Dictionary<int, Sprite[]>();

    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
      spriteList.Add(i, Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Spritesheets/" + name + "/" + (i + 1)));
    }

    return spriteList;
  }

  void Awake() {
    spriteGroup.Add("pants", getAllSprites("pants", PANTS_LIMIT));
    spriteGroup.Add("boots", getAllSprites("boots", BOOTS_LIMIT));
    spriteGroup.Add("shirt", getAllSprites("shirt", SHIRT_LIMIT));
    spriteGroup.Add("tunic", getAllSprites("tunic", TUNIC_LIMIT));
    spriteGroup.Add("belt", getAllSprites("belt", BELT_LIMIT));

    heroSprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Spritesheets/hero/hero-body");
  }
}
```

SpritePosition.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SpritePosition : MonoBehaviour {
  [SerializeField] private string objectName;
  [SerializeField] private int objectIndex;
  [SerializeField] private int objectR;
  [SerializeField] private int objectG;
  [SerializeField] private int objectB;
  private Rigidbody2D body;
  private SpriteRenderer objectRenderer;
  private GameObject hero;
  private Rigidbody2D heroRigidBody;
  private SpriteRenderer heroRenderer;
  // private Sprite currentHeroSprite;
  private AnimationController animationControllerScript;
  private int currentHeroSpriteIndex;
  private HeroResources heroResourcesScript;
  private HeroMovement heroMovementScript;
  private Sprite[] spriteGroup;

  private void Start() {
    body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    objectRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

    hero = GameObject.Find("Hero");
    heroRigidBody = hero.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    heroRenderer = hero.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    animationControllerScript = hero.GetComponent<AnimationController>();
    currentHeroSpriteIndex = animationControllerScript.currentHeroSpriteIndex;

    heroResourcesScript = hero.GetComponent<HeroResources>();
    spriteGroup = heroResourcesScript.spriteGroup[objectName][objectIndex];
  }

  private void Update() {
    heroMovementScript = hero.GetComponent<HeroMovement>();

    SetSprite();
    SetPosition();
  }
  
  private void SetSprite() {
    if (currentHeroSpriteIndex != animationControllerScript.currentHeroSpriteIndex) {
      currentHeroSpriteIndex = animationControllerScript.currentHeroSpriteIndex;
      objectRenderer.sprite = spriteGroup[currentHeroSpriteIndex];
    }

    objectRenderer.color = new Color(objectR, objectG, objectB, 1);
    transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
  }

  // for this to work, the game object must have a
  // RigidBody2D component with Freeze Position active
  // for X and Y axis
  private void SetPosition() {
    Vector2 currentHeroPosition = heroRigidBody.position;
    transform.position = currentHeroPosition;
  }
}
```

The only real issue now is that the renderer for the Hero game object doesn't seem to update the sprite as it is set.

Comment: Where have you updated **currentHeroSpriteIndex** of __SpritePosition__ script, when there is a change in **currentHeroSpriteIndex** of __AnimationController__ script? The **currentHeroSpriteIndex** of __SpritePosition__ scripts always has value 0, since it is only assigned once in *Start* method.

Comment: Oh you’re right, I probably should check for change on that value and reassign on `update`

Comment: @nIcEcOw I updated to use a condition `if (currentHeroSpriteIndex != animationControllerScript.currentHeroSpriteIndex)` and while they now update, the transition is really fast. How do I specify the frequency (in milliseconds) to run the `Update` function?

Comment: @gfcf14 Use [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html). It is the time elapsed since the last frame in second. It is a float, so you can just convert seconds to milliseconds. Track how much time has passed and if enough has passed, then increment the index and reset the timer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue to be a logic error. You mentioned that your sprite index is always 0. Here's how I see the issue.

In `AnimationController.cs`, in the `Update` method, you have the conditional

```
if (running) 
{
    currentHeroSpriteIndex = runningSprites[animationIndex % 14];
    setHeroSprite(currentHeroSpriteIndex);
    animationIndex++;
} 
else 
{
    currentHeroSpriteIndex = 0;
    setHeroSprite(currentHeroSpriteIndex);
    animationIndex = 0;
}
```

As I understand it, the statement is depending on if the bool `running` is true or false. Whenever it is false, the index is set back to 0.

Right above the conditional, you are doing the assignment of this variable

```
running = heroMovementScript.isRunning;
```

Going through the object type, `heroMovementScript` is of type `HeroMovement`, so the field `isRunning` is set in this respective scripts `Update` function

```
void Update()
{
 ... 
 isRunning = horizontalInput != 0 && !isJumping && !isFalling;
 ...
}
```

As I see it, the bool `isRunning` in this script completely determines if your index of the animation updates, or if it results in index 0 continually. In short, I believe this condition is not what you expect and is always false, resulting in no update to your animation index.

Comment: I'm following @nIcEcOw 's comment above, and decided to change the sprite update to occur inside the `HeroMovement` script (and that way the `AnimationController` will only deal with animation changes), but as I doing the same with the Hero object, I get an out of bounds error. I changed my Resources load to use `heroSprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Spritesheets/hero");` but somehow it seems the Sprite array comes back null https://www.dropbox.com/s/i189llfkfp1tcfe/updatedcode.jpg?dl=0 https://www.dropbox.com/s/yj2kg1b44crz5hv/filetree.jpg?dl=0

Comment: @gfcf14 If the line is exactly as you have written, it is because you have given an incomplete path to the sprite. It has to read `heroSprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Spritesheets/hero/heor-body.png");`. I assumed you used a `.png` extension, if not replace that portion.

Comment: I tried changing the line to use `heroSprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Spritesheets/hero/hero-body.png");` instead, but I keep getting an IndexOutOfBounds.

Comment: Where exactly do you get `IndexOutOfBounds`?

Comment: I'm getting it in this line `heroRenderer.sprite = heroSprites[currentHeroSpriteIndex];` from the updated code at https://www.dropbox.com/s/i189llfkfp1tcfe/updatedcode.jpg?dl=0

Comment: I can't really debug this for you. You'd either get that if `currentHeroSpriteIndex` is -1 or larger than the container `heroSprites`.

Comment: I’ll try to debug log the array length and the index to use, but it should be within the specified values in `private int[] runningSprites = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 };`

Comment: @gfcf14 The issue is most likely the data is not loading properly and the length of the sprite container is 0 instead of what you are expecting. It is very easy to debug. Just use a `Debug.Log(yourContainer.Length)` if it is an array or `(Debug.Log(yourContainer.Count)` if it is a list. If the size is anything other than the total you expect, that is your issue.

Comment: I changed the loading line to be `heroSprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Spritesheets/hero/hero-body");` and it seems to load the sprites. I then updated the `heroSprites` inside `HeroMovement.cs` to update with the one from the `HeroResources.cs` script if they don't match length. But then, I do `heroRenderer.sprite = heroSprites[currentHeroSpriteIndex];` and while the sprite does change (I did a `Debug.Log` to show the name) the hero game object's sprite is not updating

Comment: Can you update the code you are now using? Edit your question to the updated code. The line you are using looks right but it could be that the sprite is being set somewhere else other than that line. Are you setting the renderers sprite somewhere else?

Comment: I updated the code, under the EDIT section

Comment: @gfcf14 I believe the issue is you are setting the `objectRenderer` sprite and the `heroRenderer` sprite. Are those different or the same? I would only set the sprite of your character in one place to de-complicate the code. I am sure that the sprite is just getting overwritten in one of these places.

Comment: while they’re both sprite renderers, I should have said  I have `SpritePosition.cs` attached to the game objects that are children of the hero game object, but not to the hero game object.

Comment: I fixed it by removing the sprite in the main game object and adding another child game object which uses the body sprites, but I get a delay between sprites. Please view this one if you can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69375350/optimizing-sprite-change-for-game-object-with-multiple-children