# Optimizing sprite change for game object with multiple children

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object structure like this:

[image]

Which I have to create a player with several different equipment. For this, I am using a custom animation controller which changes an index that would determine sprites out of a few spritesheets:

`AnimationController.cs`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimationController : MonoBehaviour {
  private float waitTime = 0.06f;
  private float timer = 0.0f;

  private bool grounded;
  private bool falling;
  private bool jumping;
  private bool running;
  private bool horizontalCollision;

  private HeroMovement heroMovementScript;
  private GameObject hero;

  private int[] runningSprites = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 };
  private int animationIndex = 0;

  public int currentHeroSpriteIndex;

  // Start is called before the first frame update
  void Start() {
    hero = GameObject.Find("Hero");
    heroMovementScript = hero.GetComponent<HeroMovement>();
  }

  // Update is called based on timer and waitTime
  void Update() {
    timer += Time.deltaTime;

    if (timer > waitTime) {
      grounded = heroMovementScript.isGrounded;
      falling = heroMovementScript.isFalling;
      jumping = heroMovementScript.isJumping;
      running = heroMovementScript.isRunning;
      horizontalCollision = heroMovementScript.horizontalCollision;

      if (running) {
        currentHeroSpriteIndex = runningSprites[animationIndex % 14];
        animationIndex++;
      } else {
        currentHeroSpriteIndex = 0;
        animationIndex = 0;
      }

      timer = timer - waitTime;
    }
  }
}
```

So here I run the `update` function a set wait time, and based on variables from a `HeroMovement` script do I update the booleans to determine how to update the index based on declared arrays:

`HeroMovement.cs`

```
using UnityEngine;

public class HeroMovement : MonoBehaviour {
  [SerializeField] private float speed;
  [SerializeField] private float jumpHeight;
  private Rigidbody2D body;
  private Animator anim;
  private AnimationController animationControllerScript;
  private int currentHeroSpriteIndex;
  private SpriteRenderer heroRenderer;
  private HeroResources heroResourcesScript;
  private Sprite[] heroSprites;
  public bool isGrounded;
  public bool isFalling;
  public bool isJumping;
  public bool isFacingLeft;
  public bool isRunning;

  public bool horizontalCollision;

  public int collisionCounter = 0;

  // called when script is loaded
  private void Awake() {
    body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    animationControllerScript = GetComponent<AnimationController>();
    heroRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    heroResourcesScript = GetComponent<HeroResources>();

    currentHeroSpriteIndex = animationControllerScript.currentHeroSpriteIndex;
    heroSprites = heroResourcesScript.heroSprites;
  }

  // called on every frame of the game
  private void Update() {
    float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float verticalSpeed = body.velocity.y;

    // x axis movement
    if (!horizontalCollision) {
      body.velocity = new Vector2(horizontalInput * speed, body.velocity.y);

      // flip player when moving left
      if (horizontalInput > 0.01f && isGrounded) {
        transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
        isFacingLeft = false;
      }
      // flip player when moving right
      else if (horizontalInput < -0.01f && isGrounded) {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
        isFacingLeft = true;
      }
    }

    // jumping
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded) {
      Jump();
    }

    isRunning = horizontalInput != 0 && !isJumping && !isFalling;

    // set animator parameters
    // anim.SetBool("isRunning", horizontalInput != 0 && !isJumping && !isFalling);
    // anim.SetBool("isGrounded", isGrounded);
    // anim.SetBool("isFalling", isFalling);
    // anim.SetBool("isJumping", isJumping);
    // anim.SetBool("horizontalCollision", horizontalCollision);

    if (!isGrounded && verticalSpeed < -1) {
      Fall();
    }
  }

  private void Fall() {
    isFalling = true;
  }

  private void Jump() {
    body.velocity = new Vector2(body.velocity.x, jumpHeight);
    isJumping = true;
    isGrounded = false;
  }

  private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
    Collider2D collider = collision.collider;
    Collider2D otherCollider = collision.otherCollider;

    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground") {
      if (otherCollider.tag == "Hero") {
        if (!isHorizontalCollision(otherCollider, collider)) {
          isGrounded = true;
          isFalling = false;
          isJumping = false;
          horizontalCollision = false;
        } else {          
          horizontalCollision = true;

          if (isBottomCollision(otherCollider, collider)) {
            horizontalCollision = false;
          }
        }
      }      
    }

    collisionCounter++;
  }

  private bool isBottomCollision(Collider2D collider1, Collider2D collider2) {
    int c1BottomEdge = (int) collider1.bounds.max.y;
    int c2TopEdge = (int) collider2.bounds.min.y;

    return c1BottomEdge == c2TopEdge;
  }

  private bool isHorizontalCollision(Collider2D collider1, Collider2D collider2) {
    int c1RightEdge = (int) collider1.bounds.max.x;
    int c1LeftEdge = (int) collider1.bounds.min.x;

    int c2RightEdge = (int) collider2.bounds.max.x;
    int c2LeftEdge = (int) collider2.bounds.min.x;

    return (c1RightEdge == c2LeftEdge) || (c1LeftEdge == c2RightEdge);
  }

  private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision) {
    collisionCounter--;

    if (collisionCounter == 0) {
      isGrounded = false;
    }
  }

  // private bool isGrounded() {
  //   RaycastHit2D raycastHit = Physics2D.BoxCast(boxCollider.bounds.center, boxCollider.bounds.size, 0, Vector2.down, 0.1f, groundLayer);
  //   return raycastHit.collider != null;
  // }
}
```

Each of the child game objects also make use of the `currentHeroSpriteIndex` to update their sprites, their color based on serialized fields, and their position based on the parent's:

`SpritePosition.cs`

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SpritePosition : MonoBehaviour {
  [SerializeField] private string objectName;
  [SerializeField] private int objectIndex;
  [SerializeField] private int objectR;
  [SerializeField] private int objectG;
  [SerializeField] private int objectB;
  private Rigidbody2D body;
  private SpriteRenderer objectRenderer;
  private GameObject hero;
  private Rigidbody2D heroRigidBody;
  private AnimationController animationControllerScript;
  private int currentHeroSpriteIndex;
  private HeroResources heroResourcesScript;
  private Sprite[] spriteGroup;

  private void Start() {
    body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    objectRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

    hero = GameObject.Find("Hero");
    heroRigidBody = hero.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    animationControllerScript = hero.GetComponent<AnimationController>();
    currentHeroSpriteIndex = animationControllerScript.currentHeroSpriteIndex;

    heroResourcesScript = hero.GetComponent<HeroResources>();
    spriteGroup = heroResourcesScript.spriteGroup[objectName][objectIndex];

    float floatR = objectR / 255f;
    float floatG = objectG / 255f;
    float floatB = objectB / 255f;

    if (objectName != "body") {
      objectRenderer.color = new Color(floatR, floatG, floatB, 1);
    }
  }

  private void Update() {
    SetSprite();
    SetPosition();
  }
  
  private void SetSprite() {
    if (currentHeroSpriteIndex != animationControllerScript.currentHeroSpriteIndex) {
      currentHeroSpriteIndex = animationControllerScript.currentHeroSpriteIndex;
      objectRenderer.sprite = spriteGroup[currentHeroSpriteIndex];
    }

    transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
  }

  // for this to work, the game object must have a
  // RigidBody2D component with Freeze Position active
  // for X and Y axis
  private void SetPosition() {
    Vector2 currentHeroPosition = heroRigidBody.position;
    transform.position = currentHeroPosition;
  }
}
```

And for this, I use another script, `HeroResources` which loads all of the sprites on Dictionaries:

`HeroResources.cs`

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HeroResources : MonoBehaviour {
  const int PANTS_LIMIT = 1;
  const int BOOTS_LIMIT = 1;
  const int SHIRT_LIMIT = 1;
  const int TUNIC_LIMIT = 2;
  const int BELT_LIMIT = 1;

  public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, Sprite[]>> spriteGroup = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, Sprite[]>>();
  public Sprite[] heroSprites = new Sprite[180];

  public Dictionary<int, Sprite[]> getAllSprites(string name, int limit) {
    Dictionary<int, Sprite[]> spriteList = new Dictionary<int, Sprite[]>();

    if (name == "hero") {
      spriteList.Add(0, Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Spritesheets/hero/hero-body"));
    } else {
      for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        spriteList.Add(i, Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Spritesheets/" + name + "/" + (i + 1)));
      }
    }

    return spriteList;
  }

  void Awake() {
    spriteGroup.Add("body", getAllSprites("hero", 1));
    spriteGroup.Add("pants", getAllSprites("pants", PANTS_LIMIT));
    spriteGroup.Add("boots", getAllSprites("boots", BOOTS_LIMIT));
    spriteGroup.Add("shirt", getAllSprites("shirt", SHIRT_LIMIT));
    spriteGroup.Add("tunic", getAllSprites("tunic", TUNIC_LIMIT));
    spriteGroup.Add("belt", getAllSprites("belt", BELT_LIMIT));

    heroSprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Spritesheets/hero/hero-body");
  }
}
```

So, to clarify: the `Hero` game object has the scripts `AnimationController`, `HeroMovement`, and `HeroResources` attached to it, while the child game objects only have the `SpritePosition` script attached.

The idea is to load the sprites, then based on the logic in the movement script, decide on the booleans to use for the animator, check which is active (currently I only have `running` working), then based on which one is true determine a sprite index to use. All sprites have the same name and dimensions which is why a single index works to change all. I'm basically doing it this way to avoid having hundreds of animations for each different equipment in use.

[image]

So, while the sprites update this way in sync, I'm not sure if I'm not optimizing the sprite changing (and redrawing in color) process, because when I press arrow keys to run, I get the following:

[image]

Although the screen recorder I used seems to slow down the playback, there are brief moments in which the hero's body is seen through the pants (and sometimes the boots) although the sprites are supposed to not overlap.

I'm not sure if this is because of a computer's memory, but there are 14 sprites used for running movement, which would amount to 84 sprites in total used in the span of the 2 or so seconds which the animation lasts. Is it that I'm using too much memory to load the sprites needed? Should I maybe try to find a way to merge sprites to only have a single child whose sprite gets updated? Please let me know if anyone has suggestions on how to improve my code's performance.

**EDIT:**

I opted to change my code to do away with the `HeroResources.cs` script which ultimately loads every available asset at the beginning to instead include the resource load in `SpritePosition.cs` so that each child game object takes care of its own spritesheet:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SpritePosition : MonoBehaviour {
  [SerializeField] private string objectName;
  [SerializeField] private int objectIndex;
  [SerializeField] private int objectR;
  [SerializeField] private int objectG;
  [SerializeField] private int objectB;
  private Rigidbody2D body;
  private SpriteRenderer objectRenderer;
  private GameObject hero;
  private Rigidbody2D heroRigidBody;
  private AnimationController animationControllerScript;
  private int currentHeroSpriteIndex;
  private Sprite[] spriteGroup;


  private void Start() {
    body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    objectRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

    hero = GameObject.Find("Hero");
    heroRigidBody = hero.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    animationControllerScript = hero.GetComponent<AnimationController>();
    currentHeroSpriteIndex = animationControllerScript.currentHeroSpriteIndex;

    if (objectName != "body") {
      LoadSpriteSheet();
    } else {
      spriteGroup = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Spritesheets/hero/hero-body");
    }
    
    float floatR = objectR / 255f;
    float floatG = objectG / 255f;
    float floatB = objectB / 255f;

    if (objectName != "body") {
      objectRenderer.color = new Color(floatR, floatG, floatB, 1);
    }
  }

  private void Update() {
    SetSprite();
    SetPosition();
  }

  private void LoadSpriteSheet() {
    spriteGroup = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Spritesheets/" + name + "/" + (objectIndex + 1));
  }
  
  private void SetSprite() {
    if (currentHeroSpriteIndex != animationControllerScript.currentHeroSpriteIndex) {
      currentHeroSpriteIndex = animationControllerScript.currentHeroSpriteIndex;
      objectRenderer.sprite = spriteGroup[currentHeroSpriteIndex];
    }

    transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
  }

  private void SetPosition() {
    Vector2 currentHeroPosition = heroRigidBody.position;
    transform.position = currentHeroPosition;
  }
}
```

This, however, doesn't seem to improve performance. I've checked the profiler using deep profiling, and though I see large spikes I don't see garbage coming from the `SetSprite` function nor much of a delay compared to `EditorLoop` or `PlayerLoop`:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I assumed there would be issues in how often the function to change sprites gets called, or how much garbage would be generated with the constant sprite changing, but it seems that this might not be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever want to discover where lag or high memory usage is coming from use the unity profiler, if possible use a 3rd party profiler because unity's is kinda meh, also use deep profiling (unity will profile every method call, good to see what changes are causing lag, remember that using the profiler will reduce performance and increase memory usage as long as you have it on). There is a lot of stuff that you NEED to improve, but all of the issues I can think off will be obvious with deep profiling.

Comment: thank you. I'll look into using a profiler for this. Will let you know if I stumble upon any code I need to change

Comment: I modified my code a bit to load from the child game object's script to attempt to load only the resources currently used, and tried to understand what the profiler shows, but I'm not sure what could be causing the delays if there is virtually no delay nor garbage collected. When you can, could you please look at the edit and tell me if I'm going over the profiler wrong or if I should try something else?